# Is the related accounts tab on our user profiles broken?

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page

When I view the Accounts tab on my profile I get the following error message:

```
Related Accounts  
Couldn't match accounts across our network of websites:  
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Hopefully this is temporary. Please refresh the page to try again
```

I also notice that the Accounts tab on my profile on the new Stack Exchange sites (e.g. on the  Food and Cooking site) no longer shows my linked accounts, is this a related problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with how we were searching for accounts on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Because Area51 isn't hosted on the same database as the main Q&A sites, we have to issue a network request to find out your account details - the data we got back remotely was handled incorrectly in your case by the Q&A sites.

This will be fixed in tonight's production deployment.  Thanks for bearing with us as we figured it out!

Comment: Working again, yay!

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me... perhaps the "hopefully this is temporary" text should be heeded? :)

Comment: Since when does anyone fully read error messages?

Comment: Still broken so not that temporary for me: http://flic.kr/p/8q5k2T

Comment: Also my meta profile says: Related Accounts
Couldn't find any accounts matching your OpenID in the network. My openid hasn't changed at all.

Comment: @kev I can't repro -- all account tabs load fine for me

Comment: @jeff - this is broken for me over two different internet connections and on multiple PC's.

Comment: @kev there's something wrong with your profile.

Comment: @Jeff as in something I've done?